# R: get dataframe row with specific characters

Tags: r, string, tibble

I need to detect rows of a df/tibble containing a specific sequence of characters.

`seq <- "RT @AventusSystems"` is my sequence

```
df <- structure(list(text = c("@AventusSystems Wow, what a upgrade from help of investor", 
"RT @AventusSystems: A recent article about our investors as shown in Forbes! t.co/n8oGwiEDpu #Aventus #GlobalAdvisors #4thefans #Ti…", 
"@AventusSystems Very nice to have this project", "RT @AventusSystems: Join the #TicketRevolution with #Aventus today! #Aventus #TicketRevolution #AventCoin #4thefans t.co/OPlyCFmW4a"
), Tweet_Id = c("898359464444559360", "898359342952439809", "898359326552633345", 
"898359268226736128"), created_at = structure(c(17396, 17396, 
17396, 17396), class = "Date")), .Names = c("text", "Tweet_Id", 
"created_at"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

select(df, contains(seq))
# A tibble: 4 x 0
```

`sapply(df$text, grepl, seq)` return only 4 FALSE

What do I wrong? What is the correct solution? 
Thank you for help

Comment: Would `grep(seq, df$text)` do it for you?

Comment: Or if you want the data frame rows that contain these characters, `filter(df, grepl(seq, text))`

Comment: @csgroen yes it does the job.TY

Comment: @Z.Lin good too. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `grepl` is already vectorized over its argument `x`, so you don't need `sapply`. You could just do `grepl(seq, df$text)`.

Why your code doesn't work is that sapply passes each element of the `X` argument to the function in `FUN` argument as the first argument (so you are looking for the search pattern "@AventusSystems Wow, what a upgrade from help of investor", etc. in your `seq` object.

Lastly, `dplyr::select` selects columns, whereas you want to use `dplyr::filter`, which filters rows.